# ansible.inventory.Inventory class replacement from Ansible 2.4+ onwards

Tags: ansible

I'm currently using ansible 2.3.3 and trying to upgrade it to a newever version but since 2.4+ the ansible.inventory.Inventory class has been removed.

Does anybody know what is the equivalent recommended replacement of ansible.inventory.Inventory in Ansible 2.4+?

```
from ansible.inventory import Inventory
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
from ansible.vars import VariableManager

inv = Inventory(
        loader = DataLoader(),
        variable_manager = VariableManager(),
        host_list = my_path,
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There [isn't a one to one replacement](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/76990) in the newer code but the following code can be used but note that the inventory now has a different data structure

```
from ansible.inventory.manager import InventoryManager
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader

m = InventoryManager(loader=DataLoader(), sources='/path/to/inventory')

m.hosts
m.groups
```